# Calculate Average correlate with 2 enum columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a table which contain 3 columns which includes 2 enum columns and 1 float column, so how to calculate the value of the last column and group it by the first column?

I'm using MySQL and tried to generate the web page using PHP Generator for MySQL professional

```sql
CREATE TABLE sample (
    R enum('R1','R2','R3','R4','R5'),
    S enum('S1','S2','S3','S4'),
    Value DECIMAL(4,3)
);
```

I want to create a new column for the average value for every `R`, based on the `Value` column.

```
| R  | S  | VALUE  | AVG VALUE |
+----+----+--------+-----------+
| R1 | S1 | 2.123  |           |
| R1 | S2 | 1.234  |  average  |
| R1 | S3 | 1.242  |           |
| R1 | S4 | 0.123  |           |
+----+----+--------+-----------+
| R2 | S1 | 2.123  |           |
| R2 | S2 | 1.234  |           |
| R2 | S3 | 1.242  |  average  |
| R2 | S4 | 0.123  |           |
+----+----+--------+-----------+
| R3 | S1 | 2.123  |           |
| R3 | S2 | 1.234  |           |
| R3 | S3 | 1.242  |  average  |
| R3 | S4 | 0.123  |           |
+----+----+--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then use `AVG()` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    R,
    S,
    VALUE,
    AVG(VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY R) AVG_VALUE
FROM sample
ORDER BY
    R, S;
```

Comment: @Strawberry Not sure what the edits have done, but I agree with you after seeing the updated question.